# R - using regex, set position before nth punct in string and delete what follows

Tags: regex, r, string, gsub, punctuation

I have a large data frame with a column of string data that currently contains a set of names and in certain instances an email address.  I'd like to find a regular expression that will allow me to set the position just before the second comma in those cases with an email address and then remove what comes after it so that I am left with an "author" column of just names, no emails included.

```
> author<-c("Doe, Jane", "Smith, John", "Doe, John, johndoe@xyz.net", "Smith, Jane")
> ID<- c(1:4)   
> df<-cbind(author, ID)

> df

  author                         ID 
[1,] Doe, Jane                   1
[2,] Smith, John                 2
[3,] Doe, John, johndoe@xyz.net  3
[4,] Smith, Jane                 4
```

I'd like the output to look as follows

```
>df

author                            ID 
[1,] Doe, Jane                    1
[2,] Smith, John                  2
[3,] Doe, John                    3
[4,] Smith, Jane                  4
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you post an example of a regular expression you've already used and that isn't working the way you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sub` function. `[^,]*` matches any character but not of `,` zero or more times.

```
> author<-c("Doe, Jane", "Smith, John", "Doe, John, johndoe@xyz.net", "Smith, Jane")
> sub("^([^,]*,[^,]*),.*", "\\1", author)
[1] "Doe, Jane"   "Smith, John" "Doe, John"   "Smith, Jane"
> ID<- c(1:4)
> df<-cbind(author=sub("^([^,]*,[^,]*),.*", "\\1", author), ID)
> df
     author        ID 
[1,] "Doe, Jane"   "1"
[2,] "Smith, John" "2"
[3,] "Doe, John"   "3"
[4,] "Smith, Jane" "4"
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `([^,]*,[^,]*)`, `(...)` called Capturing group  used to capture those characters which are matched by the pattern present inside that capturing group. In our case , the pattern present inside the capturing group is `[^,]*,[^,]*`. I already mentioned that this `[^,]*` matches any character but not of comma, zero or more times. So `[^,]*,[^,]*` matches all the characters from the start until the second comma is reached. `([^,]*,[^,]*)` captures those matched characters and stored it into the group index 1. We could refer the characters which are present inside the capturing group by specifying it's index number. This is called **back-referencing**.
- `,.*` Now this matches the second comma and the following zero or more characters.
- `sub` and `gsub` functions will replace all the matched characters with the string mentioned in the replacement part. So in our case, all the matched characters are replaced by the chars inside group index 1. That's why we used `\\1` in the replacement part.

Comment: or `sub("^[^,]*,[^,]*\\K,.*", "", author,perl=T)`

Comment: we don't need to match the email-id's. Second comma is great a clue here.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: one clarifying question:  what is the purpose of entering "\\1" in the sub call?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't regex but woud work for this situation.  The **qdap** package that I maintain has the `beg2char` (beginning of strung to a character) for this.  You can specify the character and which one (here we want the second one).  The complementary function is `char2end`:

```
library(qdap)
df[, "ID"] <- beg2char(author, ",", 2)

##      author                       ID           
## [1,] "Doe, Jane"                  "Doe, Jane"  
## [2,] "Smith, John"                "Smith, John"
## [3,] "Doe, John, johndoe@xyz.net" "Doe, John"  
## [4,] "Smith, Jane"                "Smith, Jane"
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've just downloaded your package.  This is much easier for me to comprehend than regular expressions.